# Uniformly Resizing a Window in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, window

Well, I am trying to give my game's window the ability to resize **uniformly**. I have checked everywhere but I can't seem to find anything about it.

Any ideas?

I can't post the code due to the character limit. It would be much appreciated if someone could please help me out and see  what I am doing wrong :)

Also helpful would be how to resize the backbuffer when this happens, as I don't think the game would be playable with only half the sprites visible :)

```
   void Window_ClientSizeChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
   {
       int new_width = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width;
       int new_height = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;

       if (new_width != Variables.SCREEN_WIDTH)
       {
           Variables.SCREEN_HEIGHT = (int)(new_width * ascept_ratio);
           Variables.SCREEN_WIDTH = new_width;
       }
       if (new_height != Variables.SCREEN_HEIGHT)
       {
           Variables.SCREEN_WIDTH = (int)(new_height / ascept_ratio);
           Variables.SCREEN_HEIGHT = new_height;
       }

       UpdateParameters();
   }
```

...

```
   public void UpdateParameters()
   {
       graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Variables.SCREEN_WIDTH;
       graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Variables.SCREEN_HEIGHT;
       graphics.ApplyChanges();
   }
```

Thanks,

Kind Regards, Darestium

Comment: Why doesn't this code work? What does it do that is undesirable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To keep the aspect ratio you mean?

You'd do this the same as any WinForms project:

When the form loads up store the aspect radio: `(float)Width/(float)Height`. In XNA, this could be in the `LoadContent` of your game (since the window would be created by then).

Then, handle the form's `sizechanged` event. You'll need to keep track of whether the user is changing height, width or both. If it's height, then set the `Width = Height / AspectRatio`, if the width changes set `Height = Width * AspectRatio`.

If both change, then decide on either width or height, (i mean pick either one in design, not each resize) and do as above.

---

You'll probably have to do things XNA-specific once you've done this, such as resize the backbuffer etc. but this isn't specific to this question so i'll leave it out (ask another question if need be).

---

**EDIT. Below is a minimal, working sample:**

It maintains aspect ratio, as well as resizes the graphics by drawing to a render target the original size of the window, then drawing that scaled to fit the new window. If you don't want this remove the overridden `BeginDraw` and `EndDraw` methods.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;

namespace WindowsGame1
{
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager Graphics;
        float AspectRatio;
        Point OldWindowSize;
        Texture2D BlankTexture;
        RenderTarget2D OffScreenRenderTarget;
        SpriteBatch SpriteBatch;

        public Game1()
        {
            Graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            Graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
            Window.AllowUserResizing = true;
            Window.ClientSizeChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Window_ClientSizeChanged);
        }

        void Window_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Remove this event handler, so we don't call it when we change the window size in here
            Window.ClientSizeChanged -= new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Window_ClientSizeChanged);

            if (Window.ClientBounds.Width != OldWindowSize.X)
            { // We're changing the width
                // Set the new backbuffer size
                Graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = Window.ClientBounds.Width;
                Graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = (int)(Window.ClientBounds.Width / AspectRatio);
            }
            else if (Window.ClientBounds.Height != OldWindowSize.Y)
            { // we're changing the height
                // Set the new backbuffer size
                Graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = (int)(Window.ClientBounds.Height * AspectRatio);
                Graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = Window.ClientBounds.Height;
            }

            Graphics.ApplyChanges();

            // Update the old window size with what it is currently
            OldWindowSize = new Point(Window.ClientBounds.Width, Window.ClientBounds.Height);

            // add this event handler back
            Window.ClientSizeChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Window_ClientSizeChanged);
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Set up initial values
            AspectRatio = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio;
            OldWindowSize = new Point(Window.ClientBounds.Width, Window.ClientBounds.Height);

            BlankTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
            BlankTexture.SetData(new Color[] { Color.FromNonPremultiplied(255, 255, 255, 255) });
            SpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            OffScreenRenderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, Window.ClientBounds.Width, Window.ClientBounds.Height);
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            if (OffScreenRenderTarget != null)
                OffScreenRenderTarget.Dispose();

            if (BlankTexture != null)
                BlankTexture.Dispose();

            if (SpriteBatch != null)
                SpriteBatch.Dispose();

            base.UnloadContent();
        }

        protected override bool BeginDraw()
        {
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(OffScreenRenderTarget);
            return base.BeginDraw();
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            SpriteBatch.Begin();
            SpriteBatch.Draw(BlankTexture, new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100), Color.White);
            SpriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void EndDraw()
        {
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
            SpriteBatch.Begin();
            SpriteBatch.Draw(OffScreenRenderTarget, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds, Color.White);
            SpriteBatch.End();
            base.EndDraw();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks :). But everything seems to work but Diagonal and Height resizing :(

Comment: Fixed a typo causing the problem.

Comment: If the user resizes width and height, it just picks the width, and resizes the height accordingly. Swap the order of the `if`s to get it to use the height, and calculate the width.

Comment: WOW! Thanks your are god :) But do you know of anyway for the stuff being display to be resized also?

Comment: I didn't test drawings, will take a quick look tomorrow. Do you mean you want it so if the window is bigger the graphics are bigger?

Comment: Yes, and same thing if you make the window smaller - it makes the graphics smaller

Comment: But how about collision detection? :) I guess I would have to calculate the difference between the original dimensions and the currect one then detect collision from there...

Comment: For collision detection between objects it would still work fine. With collision detection with the mouse you'd have to work out where the mouse is relative to the render target size, which would be something like `WorldSpaceMouse = Mouse.Position / ActualWindowSize * RenderTargetSize`

Comment: Note that maintaining the aspect ratio is determined by the real backbuffer size. The offscreen target has a very different purpose.   Example of that would be to up/down sample a GUI that is coded for a fixed resolution (does not perform layouts, controls are at fixed positions/sizes), and you are willing to accept the loss of bitmap/text quality.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that this code won't work because it will keep calling itself, because the ClientSizeChanged event will fire the ClientSizeChanged event.

Maybe you need to check and see if the window is already in the correct aspect ratio, and not change it further.

Comment: Anyone have any other ideas? Because I seem to be all out of them ;) and sorry about the previous post I didn't know I could edit posts like that.

Comment: @Darestium It would be helpful if you described the behavior that you're seeing with your current code.

Comment: Well... It just doesn't resize the window properly, or in other cases doesn't let me resize it. And sometimes it doesn't do anything :)