# XNA window erroneously scaled, fixed with window resize

Tags: xna, window, scale

So I am using this code to handle the rendering at any resolution:

```
int windowW = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width; //Save the current screen size
int windowH = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height;
RenderTarget2D screen = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, 1024, 768,
    false, GraphicsDevice.DisplayMode.Format, DepthFormat.Depth24, 8, RenderTargetUsage.DiscardContents);
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(screen);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

soldrGameHub.Render(gameTime, spriteBatch); //Render all to another RenderTarget

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);
spriteBatch.Begin();

float scaleX = windowW / 1024f; //The scales on each dimension, to keep the aspect ratio
float scaleY = windowH / 768f;
float scale;
Vector2 position; //and the position to make sure we render in the center

if (scaleX <= scaleY) { //screen taller than wide
    scale = scaleX;
    position = new Vector2(0, (windowH - 768 * scale) / 2f);
}
else {
    scale = scaleY;
    position = new Vector2((windowW - 1024 * scale) / 2f, 0);
}
soldrGameHub.SetMouseOffset((int) position.X, (int) position.Y); //Set the mouse offset
soldrGameHub.SetScale(scale); //and scale to get the right coordinates at any time.

spriteBatch.Draw(screen, position, null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0); //and finally draw the renderTarget to the screen.

spriteBatch.End();
```

So basically: I'm rendering everything assuming that the resolution is 1024x768, rendering to a RenderTarget and finally drawing the RenderTarget on the screen. I have to correct the mouse positions (which are handled in another class) to use the offset (so to keep the active area centered) and the scale (in order to fill the entire screen). **This IS working on 99% of the cases, EXCEPT at the beggining, before I resize the screen** (in the classical windows style, by dragging the lower-right corner with the mouse). **So, if it is resized, it works, otherwise it doesn't.**

What is happening is that the **screen is scaled** only vertically. (**For example, something that should be 75x75 is 75x73**) The result is that towards the bottom of the screen, the mouse is shown to be higher than it actually is (you have to click lower than you should). This doesn't seem to be a problem with the mouse, but instead, with the way the window is handled (the rendering is scaled without me knowing). **When the screen is at 1024x768 (before resizing), windowW and windowH are 1024 and 768 respectively, and scaleX and scaleY are both 1.0.** What is really weird is that **if I resize the window, the problem goes completely away.**

What I've tried:

1. Change the `int windowW = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width` to use `Window.ClientBounds`. I am getting another height, but otherwise exactly the same problem.
2. Resize the original window, (start at 1024x600). This actually worked, but I'm worried about the underlying problem.
3. I've used the Snipping Tool to make sure that there actually is a problem with the rendering. The 75x73 example is actually taken from the Snipping Tool with Paint.NET.

I am stuck, it seems as the problem is somewhere with XNA, can anyone help me?

TL;DR: The code is probably not that important, please read the text or, at least, the text in bold.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uniformly Resizing a Window in XNA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396677/uniformly-resizing-a-window-in-xna)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up starting the window maximized, that seems to work around the problem.

If anyone actually finds a real solution, please let me know.