# XNA C# GUI, Buttons and UI resize

Tags: c#, xna

I'm currently working on further developing an Open Source client for a game called Endless Online, right now I'm a little stuck with the UI; For example, I've fixed the resizing so the interface does scale with window size, however this is what happens:

**[Normal Window Size]** (The minimum and the size the UI is being defined to)
[image]

**[~1920x1080 window size]**
[image]

On the normal screen size, the UI works fine.
But on anything higher, I can only interact with them from their original position.

I can provide code if needed

Comment: try here
http://www.discussiongenerator.com/2012/09/15/resolution-independent-2d-rendering-in-xna-4/

Comment: I've tried using the Resolution Independent rendering, but it doesn't scale everything as I resize the window.
The closest I've come was through this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396677/uniformly-resizing-a-window-in-xna